# How to Deploy Static html/js App using VSTS Continuous Integration and Azure

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to deploy an Angular app to Azure Web App using VSTS Continuous Integration.

My repository doesn't contain any .sln .pdb, it's just a static web site.
I have define my build to run npm, gulp, but I don't know how to create an artifact without building the the vs solution.
I would also need to create a release task to publish the web site to azure.

Does anybody has a build definition that would work for this deployment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add "Copy and Publish Build Artifacts" task to copy and publish the deployment files to artifact folder that can be used in "Release Management".

And then you can enable ["FTP Deployment"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#ftp) for your Azure Web App and use ["FTP Uploader"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task) task to publish the files to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this a few ways:

- Use azure git deploy.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/  I bake the git credentials into a script, and force commit and publish the site to the azure url.
- Use Publish-WebApplicationWebsite.ps1 from the Azure SDK https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-publish-webapplicationwebsite-windows-powershell-script/  I recall handing it a folder, but it appears the current version takes in an MSDeploy package.